# Setting up HTTPS for a website hosted in AWS, but points to a webAPI in the local area network

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, certbot

I'm working on a project where we're hosting a webpage on AWS. The webpage calls a webAPI from a local area network computer name IE: Server-24.Local.
This approach ensures data doesn't leave the network as Server-24.Local is not exposed to the internet.
This approach has worked well so far. However, I am facing issues when i enable HTTPS via certbot:

If i try proxy_pass nginx to a webapi hosted in AWS on localhost, HTTPS works fine.
However, if i proxy_pass nginx to Server-24.Local, it returns cross-origin errors.
Both webAPIs are CORS-enabled.

Might anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

you can research about Nginx CORS enabled in internet... It's about end user browser security in chrome etc...

Here is an example, put it inside location tag {}

```
#
# Wide-open CORS config for nginx
#
location / {
     if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        #
        # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        #
        # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
     }
     if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
     }
     if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
     }
}
```

you can help look at here [https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html] ...

hopefully this help you...